# MySQL query recipe with all incredients available

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have 4 MySQL tables:

```
recipe: id, name
incredient: id, name
recipe_incredient: id, recipe_id, incredient_id
available: id, incredient_id
```

I want to have a query, which returns all recipes + incredient which there are incredients for.

Example:

I have Toast (= bread + ham) and Soup (= ham + chicken).
I have bread and ham.
Therefore I want to get Toast, but no Soup.

```
recipes:
1, Toast
2, Soup

incredients:
1, bread
2, ham
3, chicken

recipe_incredient:
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 2, 2
3, 2, 3

available:
1, 1
2, 2


Result should be:
Toast, bread
Toast, ham
```

Comment: looks like task on school, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Not really =) This is a simplified version of my problem. I am stuck on the exclusion part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exclusion part is a *double* `NOT EXISTS` clause: Find recipes where "not exists" an ingredient that is "not available".

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5144c/2/0)

```
select r.name as recipe, i.name as incredient
  from recipe r
  join recipe_incredient ri on ri.recipe_id = r.id
  join incredient i on i.id = ri.incredient_id
 where not exists (
          select *
            from recipe_incredient ri2
           where ri2.recipe_id = r.id
             and not exists (
                    select *
                      from available a
                     where a.incredient_id = ri2.incredient_id
                 )
       )
```

Can also be done using `NOT IN`.

```
select r.name as recipe, i.name as incredient
  from recipe r
  join recipe_incredient ri on ri.recipe_id = r.id
  join incredient i on i.id = ri.incredient_id
 where r.id not in (
          select ri2.recipe_id
            from recipe_incredient ri2
           where ri2.incredient_id not in (
                    select a.incredient_id
                      from available a
                 )
       )
```

Whichever is best depends on available indexes, the SQL Optimizer, and your personal preference.

Comment: Is there a reason you use join instead of:   
`FROM recipe r, recipe_incredient, incredient
WHERE  recipe_incredient.recipe_id = r.id
AND  recipe_incredient.incredient_id = incredient.id`

Comment: @Klaus See [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1018822/5221149).